# encode json from javascript and decode using php

Tags: php, javascript, json

i have to encode an array of email addresses using javascript into json string and send to abc.php using ajax. in abc.php i have to decode it and send emails to all the address into that array.

currently i'm encoding the array into json using

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(myarray);
```

in abc.php i am decoding it using

```
$emails = json_decode($_POST['json_string']);
// json_string was passed as POST variable using ajax
```

but it gives NULL when printed..

how can i decode it and access individual emails in the php file

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['json_string'])` give you, or `var_dump($_POST)` for that matter?

Comment: print_r gives
[\"abc@gmail.com\",\"def@ptas.com.np\"]

and var_dump (json_decode($_POST['json_string'])) gives null

Comment: Looks like [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?

Comment: It may be helpful to see your actual ajax call. It may be a datatype thing.

Comment: Yeah, could be magic quotes. Try unescaping the string before decoding.

Comment: better yet, turn off magic quotes. They should never be used.

Comment: thanks you all.. yes  magic quotes was the problem. I am clear now.

Comment: maybe you could flag the answer as accepted then..?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the php.ini of your webserver, the best thing would be to disable magic_quotes at all, because they are *deprecated*:

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

If you don't have server access, use a .htaccess file with the following option

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

If you don't want to use that, the last thing that remains is using an unescape function such as

```
function ref_stripslashes(&$value,$key) {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}

if((function_exists("get_magic_quotes_gpc") && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) || (ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase') && (strtolower(ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))!="off")) ) {
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,'ref_stripslashes');
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,'ref_stripslashes');
    array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE,'ref_stripslashes');
}
```

This was taken from [the php manual, Lucifer's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

`json_decode($_POST['json_string'])` should then work.